# SPOCK: How to mock supplier behavior

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, mockito, spock

I am trying to cover the positive negative scenario while executing a `supplier` inside `CompletableFuture`. For some reason the mocked values are not getting passed within the `supplier`. My unit test cases are written using spock framework, and since I am not that familiar with this framework, I am not sure that I am mistaking while mocking or there is something with the supplier mocking that I am missing.

Code under test:

```
CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(() -> s3Service.upload(bucket, key, file), executor)
    .handle(((putObjectResult, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable != null) {
            CustomRuntimeException exception = (CustomRuntimeException) throwable;
            log.error(exception);
        }
        return putObjectResult;
    }))
    .thenAccept(putObjectResult -> {
        if (putObjectResult != null) {
             FileUtils.deleteQuietly(file);
             log.debug("Deleted file {}", file.getName());
        }
    });
```

Spock test code:

```
@SpringBean
private S3Service s3service = Mock()

def "failed to upload article into s3"() {
    given: "mock the s3 service to throw CustomRuntimeException"
    s3Service.upload(_, _, _) >> {

        CompletableFuture<PutObjectResult> exception = new CompletableFuture<>();
        exception.completeExceptionally(new CustomRuntimeException())
        exception.exceptionally(new Function<Throwable, PutObjectResult>() {
            @Override
            PutObjectResult apply(Throwable throwable) {
                throw new CompletionException(throwable)
            }
        })

    }
```

Now when I debug the unit test cases the `throwable` instance in `.handle` is always `null`. Also the same is happening when I mock the `PutObjectResult`

Comment: Can you provide more code? Preferably an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LeonardBrünings thx. But finally managed to solve the issue.

Comment: Please share how you solved your issue, if you still remember.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems my understanding of given and when are different from that of Mockito framework.
I had put that my  `s3Service.upload(_, _, _)` in the `then` section and text cases works as expected. So the final code is:

```
@SpringBean
private S3Service s3service = Mock()

def "failed to upload article into s3"() {
    given: "mock the s3 service to throw CustomRuntimeException"
    // given conditions
    when: "check here the with the actual beans"
    // actual bean calls
    then: "mention your mocks and calls"
    1 * s3Service.upload(_, _, _) >> {

        CompletableFuture<PutObjectResult> exception = new CompletableFuture<>();
        exception.completeExceptionally(new CustomRuntimeException())
        exception.exceptionally(new Function<Throwable, PutObjectResult>() {
            @Override
            PutObjectResult apply(Throwable throwable) {
                throw new CompletionException(throwable)
            }
        })

    }
```